# Mysql primary key and foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm having a table of user information.
Primary key: userID int

I want to map a contact list for each user so I build another table with 2 fields:

userId, contactId both int

Now I want that both fields will be together a primary key
so  will be able to save several unique contacts id for each user Id referred to first table, and of course do an inner join with on contactID with userID

How do I do that in mysql(using phpMyAdmin)?
Query examples are also possible of course

Comment: se a related youtube video here www.youtube.com/watch?v=A42FG4LzdbY